# Unknown column in on clause even the column exists

Tags: mysql

The following MySQL 5.7.19 script raises an error `Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'ps.employeeId' in 'on clause'`.

```
SELECT
    `ps`.`employeeId`
FROM
    tablePS AS `ps`,
    tableFO AS `fo`
LEFT JOIN
   tableWA AS `wa`
ON
    `wa`.`employeeId` = `ps`.`employeeId`
```

The script runs without an error is I remove the second table in the FROM clause

```
,
        tableFO AS `fo`
```

or replace the ON clause

```
    `wa`.`employeeId` = `ps`.`employeeId`
```

with

```
    `wa`.`employeeId` = 4
```

You can create the tables with these command

```
CREATE TABLE tablePS (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED auto_increment,
    `employeeId` INT UNSIGNED,
    PRIMARY KEY `id` (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE tableFO (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED auto_increment,
    PRIMARY KEY `id` (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE tableWA (
    `id` INT UNSIGNED auto_increment,
    `employeeId` INT UNSIGNED,
    PRIMARY KEY `id` (`id`)
);
```

What's wrong?

Comment: Wrong: we can't *see* the tables in question, can we? We can't see them because you didn't post the table create statements. So what's wrong? The only possible conclusion is that the column doesn't exist. Just like MySQL is telling you.

Comment: I were in the process in trying to find a simplified CREATE TABLE statements. Question updated.

Comment: What happens if you use an explicit join for `tablePS` and `tableFO` instead of just comma-separating them?

Comment: The `ps`.`employeeId` column is used as a response column and as MySQL does not complain about it and runs the query (after the modification), I would consider it as a proof that it exists.

Comment: @David If the `CROSS JOIN` is the right equivalent, it seems to work. `... FROM
    tablePS AS ps
CROSS JOIN
    tableFO AS fo
LEFT JOIN ...`

Comment: I find it a little odd that PS and FO don't relate; cross joins are **usually** not the correct type of join.  Don't get me wrong there is a time and place to use cross joins; but without understanding the actual data in the tables (what is the entity tracking)and business case can't say if it's the "correct" approach here.

Comment: As already mentioned. Please don't mix comma separated tables in the 'FROM' list with direct joins using 'ON' clauses. It will confuse both other programmers and the SQL Parser? :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT
    `ps`.`employeeId`
FROM
    tablePS AS `ps`
CROSS JOIN
    tableFO AS `fo`
LEFT JOIN
   tableWA AS `wa`
ON
    `wa`.`employeeId` = `ps`.`employeeId`
```